# having trouble getting desired response from django restframework

Tags: django, flutter, django-models, django-rest-framework, djongo

I am working on an app based on Flutter (frontend), django (backend), mongodb atlas (database).

In my app users can add posts, like, or comment on those posts (just like facebook!)

in django my models.py has separate tables for Posts, Reacts on Posts (for like button), comments on posts. here is the code for my
**models.py**

```
class PostsComments(models.Model):
    commentID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    createTime = models.TextField()
    updateTime = models.TextField()
    approved = models.BooleanField(default= True, editable= True)
    userID = models.ForeignKey('Users', on_delete=models.CASCADE, name="userID")
    postID = models.ForeignKey('Posts', on_delete=models.CASCADE, name="postID")

class PostsReacts(models.Model):
    reactID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    createTime = models.TextField()
    updateTime = models.TextField()
    react = models.BooleanField(default= False, editable= True)
    userID = models.ForeignKey('Users', on_delete=models.CASCADE, name="userID")
    postID = models.ForeignKey('Posts', on_delete=models.CASCADE, name="postID")

class Posts(models.Model):
    postID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    createTime = models.TextField()
    updateTime = models.TextField()
    approved = models.BooleanField(default= True, editable= True)
    hasVideo = models.BooleanField(default= False, editable= True)
    hasImage = models.BooleanField(default= False, editable= True)
    #images = ListField(models.TextField)
    #videos = ListField(models.TextField)
    images = models.TextField()
    videos = models.TextField()
    #comments = [PostsComments()]
    #reacts = [PostsReacts()]
    customerID = models.ForeignKey('Customers', on_delete=models.CASCADE, name="customerID")
    def __str__(self):
        return f"ID: {self.postID}"
```

**view.py**

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponseRedirect
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.serializers import Serializer

#seerializers
from .serializers import BookingHistorySerializer, BookingSerializer, CommentsSerializer, CustomerSerializer, ExpertSerializer, PostsSerializer, PriceListSerializer, ReactsSerializer, ServicesSerializer, UserSerializer
from .models import Bookings, BookingsHistory, PostsComments, PostsReacts, PriceList, Services, Users, Experts, Customers, Posts

@api_view(['POST','GET'])
def getBlogs(request):
    blogs = Posts.objects.all()
    serializer = PostsSerializer(blogs, many = True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

my PostSerializer looks like this,

```
class PostsSerializer(ModelSerializer):    

    class Meta:
        model = Posts
        fields = '__all__'
```

I am trying to send data such that when my flutter app makes a request to retrieve posts, all posts are shared, in that I have no trouble as I am easily able to achieve it via the above code. In addition to sending just posts, I want to make sure that the current user who is logged in and is using the app, is able to see in which posts he has commented or reacted.

here is the desired response I want django to send to my frontend.

```
{
[
    {
        "postID": 1,
        "content": "this post has no video",
        "createTime": "November 9, 2021",
        "updateTime": "November 9, 2021",
        "approved": true,
        "hasVideo": false,
        "hasImage": false,
        "images": "",
        "videos": "",
        "customerID": 1
along with the above data I want information about whether the current users has liked this post or not, lets suppose user has liked it earlier so,
        "react": True
    },
    {
        "postID": 2,
        "content": "demo post 2",
        "createTime": "November 10, 2021",
        "updateTime": "November 10, 2021",
        "approved": true,
        "hasVideo": false,
        "hasImage": false,
        "images": "",
        "videos": "",
        "customerID": 1
along with the above data I want information about whether the current users has liked this post or not, lets suppose user has not liked it earlier so,
        "react": False
    }
]
```

I am sorry if my question is not clear enough, in any case if further information is required do ask for it.
any help will be appreciated TIA.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here

```json
{
  [ // here you don't specify a json key for this list of object
    {
        "postID": 1,
        "content": "this post has no video",
        "createTime": "November 9, 2021",
    },
  ]
}
```

```json
{
  "items" : [ // just do it like this
    {
        "postID": 1,
        "content": "this post has no video",
        "createTime": "November 9, 2021",
    },
  ]
}
```

And may I suggest your for json parsing in flutter you can use tools like [Quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io/)

Thanks

Comment: thanks for the resource, though I have no trouble in sending the data as is, what I want to do is share information about whether a user has liked a certain post or not along with the post data!